# How to Sign Up a User in AWS Cognito Using an OIDC Token from Google SignIn SDK?

Tags: oauth, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I have successfully implemented a login flow using the hosted UI of AWS Cognito, which involves signing in with Google, redirecting to Cognito, and then redirecting back to my app with a code. This standard flow works fine.

However, my goal is to directly use the Google SignIn SDK in my app for the login process. After logging in through the Google SignIn SDK, I receive an OIDC token. I'm interested in knowing if there's a way to use this OIDC token for signing up or signing in a user in AWS Cognito.

In my research, I came across a method where someone suggested reading the payload of the OIDC token and using the email as the username and the 'sub' field as the password for signing up in Cognito. However, I'm hesitant to adopt this approach due to potential security concerns.

Is there a more secure and direct way to use the OIDC token obtained from the Google SignIn SDK for user authentication with AWS Cognito?